# Spring Kafka Prometheus lag metrics either 0 or NaN

Tags: java, prometheus, spring-kafka, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am using spring boot 2.3.5 and using spring-cloud-stream kafka-streams binder Hoxton.SR8 version.

I am also using actuator to publish metrics from /prometheus endpoint. It also shows Kafka metrics. I want to work wih Kafka consumer lag metrics. But I am seeing them all wrong.

Almost always I see lag_max or lag metrics as either 0 or NaN. When I check lag using kafka-console-consumer script it shows me correct lag figure. Sometimes figure shown on /prometheus endpoint are way higher than what is showin via console-consumer script.

I see metrics like this

```
kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag{appName="EventValidator.local.2",client_id="EventValidator.local.2-StreamThread-1-consumer",env="local",instanceId="2",kafka_version="2.5.1",partition="0",spring_id="streams.0",topic="event-store",} 0.0

kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_max{appName="EventValidator.local.2",client_id="EventValidator.local.2-StreamThread-1-consumer",env="local",instanceId="2",kafka_version="2.5.1",partition="0",spring_id="streams.0",topic="event-store",} 0.0
```

So here lag is shown consistently as 0 when console-consumer utility is showing non-zero lag.

I tried using a different version micrometer seeing a github issue mentioned here.
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2726

Version I am using is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

What can be done in this case?

Comment: Please try to use the latest version of Micrometer, also, check if it is not the Kafka Java client that reports these values as 0 or NaN.